# highcharts How to automatically extended columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

hi all:can i automatically extended columns with a empty value like this:

[image: chart]?

[code link](http://jsfiddle.net/rKBjq/)
Thanks a lot!

```
john's value = 0 in second column
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this option is not available.